# How do I see that $\frac{1}{t} \int_0^t \frac{ds}{\ln(s)}$ goes to zero for $t$ approaching zero?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis

How do I see that $$\frac{1}{t} \int_0^t \frac{ds}{\ln(s)}$$ goes to zero for $t$ approaching zero? I don't want to use any properties of this function that are not widely known and I just want to look at the positive limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use L'hospital's rule and the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: of course, how could I have missed the most obvious one...

Comment: Actually one only needs the fundamental theorem.